# Certain text must be selectable on ipad but isn't

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, safari

My question is about a website containing certain codes people need to be able to copy-paste.
I am unable to post a link to the example because I am working for a client. That wouldn't be appropiete. I can explain the problem using StackOverflow though:

Please check the following URL on an iPad 2 or 3: https://stackoverflow.com/tour 
Use Safari browser for this.

By holding your finger on the word "Welcome" in the title it will select that word only.
By holding your finger on the word "question" in the first text-section ("Stack Overflow is a question and answer site ...etc") you won't be able to select that word, because it will select the whole textblock instead.

Now this may be fine in this case. But I need to know the logic behind it. The problem I'm having is that we have:

Some textlines. Below that on the left site we have a small text (in a seperate div) en a textual code on the right side (also in a seperate div).
There is a container around those items because otherwise we wouldn't be able to create certain markup.

When we try to select that textual code it will instead select the whole container.
But: if we zoom in, we are able to select more specific items (but still not what we want).

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this problem? Do we have to fiddle with z-indexes or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a CSS related issue or not. It is hard to tell without seeing the actual page.

The `-webkit-user-select: none;` controls the text selection of the current element.

 
But as you mentioned while zooming in you are able to select , so maybe it is not CSS related.

Unfortunately, I do not have an Ipad to test it, but I can suggest an alternative way which is to add maybe a button/anchor and on a click event to copy the textarea's content to the clipboard...
 Not supported in all browserss due to security issues but there are many workarounds/plugins. In IE you can do :

```
function copy (text)
{
window.clipboardData.setData('Text',text);
}
```

You can have a look at this [solution](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20091219184623/http://beckelman.net/demos/jQueryCopyToClipboard/Default.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe the webkit-user-select isn't there, so that shouldn't be the problem.
I was thinking about looking into other solutions as well - like the auto-copy jquery - but still would like to know what the logic is for being able to select a word or not.

Comment: sure that was just a random guess :)